# Mongodb replication on port 443

Tags: mongodb, port, replication, database-replication

Need Some help on mongodb replication on port `443`, I am running 3 mongodb instances on 3 different machines, I configured mongodb to run on the default port which is `27017`.

Now, with the port number `27017` open everything works fine but if I block the port `27017` and allow `443` and create an `IPtable` to redirect the request from `443 to 27017`, none of the mongdb machines is talking to each other.

however I am able to connect to through `443` from one machine to another manually, by specifying the `host name and port number`.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Voted to close this as off-topic, since it is not directly related to programming. It rather belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg , Before suggesting someone to close it, please let me know if you know anything about this question?

Comment: It simply Isn't a programming question and should be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Definitely a more appropriate question for DBA StackExchange. Replication (and drivers) use hostnames and ports as per your [replica set configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/), so port forwarding won't work (as you've discovered). If you are trying to set up a secure network for replica set nodes on different networks I would suggest looking into a VPN instead. Also worth reviewing the [Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the MongoDB manual for best practices.